# Class template linker error

Tags: c++

I've been trying to create a class cartesian which objects are 2 points on the a cartesian point (int or double). Then I want to overload <<.  I get the error message :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cartesian<double, int>::cartesian(double, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I dont understand where is  My mistake.

THE HEADER

```
#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;

template <class first, class second>
class cartesian
{

public:
    cartesian(first, second);

    //double getslope(cartesian &obj1, cartesian &obj2);

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, cartesian &cPoint);                

private:
    first x;
    second y;

};
```

**THE CPP file**

```
#include "cartesian.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template<class first,class second>

cartesian<first, second>::cartesian(first a, second b)
:x(a), y(b)
{}

/*
// between obj1 and obj2
template<class first,class second>
double cartesian<first, second>::getslope(cartesian &obj1, cartesian &obj2){

    return ((obj2.y-obj1.y)/(obj2.x-obj1.y));
}

*/


template<class first,class second>

ostream&  operator<< (ostream &out,const cartesian<first, second> &cPoint)
{
    // Since operator<< is a friend of the Point class, we can access
    // Point's members directly.
    out << "(" << cPoint.x << ", " <<
    cPoint.y << ")";

    return out;
}
```

THE MAIN

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cartesian.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cartesian<double, int> ob11(3.4, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ template, linking error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353973/c-template-linking-error)

Comment: The problem is that working with large templated projects in C++ is terrible. Try `#include cartesian.cpp` in main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the implementation in the header file or in a file included by the header. The compiler needs access to the code in order to "build" the `cartesian<double, int>` specialization you require in `main`.

For example, here we put the constructor's implementation in the class declaration:

```
template <class first, class second>
class cartesian
{

public:
    cartesian(first, second) :x(a), y(b) {}
};
```

It doesn't have to go inside the class declaration itself, but the code must be accessible from the header file.

Comment: What to you mean by putting the implementation in the header file? what implementation? sorry for my noobness.

Comment: @EEstud I mean the definitions of the functions, i.e. the stuff you currently have in the ``.cpp`` file.

Comment: So, I need to construct my functions in the header file  as well?
Normally we do this in the cpp, but because it is a template, I need to construct it in the header file? Did I understand well?

Comment: @EEstud correct, and remove the ``.cpp``, some build systems might try to compile it automatically.