# C++ about function templates

Tags: c++, linux, templates, g++

since 2 hours I struggle with templates, lets consider these files :

### ChildrenOfBodom.h :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void AreYouDeadYet(string);
template<typename T1>void InYourFace(T1);
```

### ChildreOfBodom.cc :

```
#include"ChildrenOfBodom.h"

void AreYouDeadYet(string s){
  InYourFace(s);
}

template<typename T1>void InYourFace(T1 t1){
  cout << t1 << endl;
}
```

### main.cc :

```
// g++ ChildrenOfBodom.cc main.cc
#include"ChildrenOfBodom.h"

int main(){
  AreYouDeadYet("Awesome");

  InYourFace("Awesome");
  int i=8;
  InYourFace(i);
  return 0;
}
```

at the compilation I got this message :

```
/tmp/ccN1fClI.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `void InYourFace<char const*>(char const*)'
main.cc:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `void InYourFace<int>(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my immediate solution was to write the function in `main.cc` (and still in `ChildrenOfBodom.cc`),

### main.cc :

```
#include"ChildrenOfBodom.h"

template<typename T1>void InYourFace(T1 t1){
  cout << t1 << endl;
}


int main(){
  AreYouDeadYet("Awesome");

  InYourFace("Awesome");
  int i=8;
  InYourFace(i);
  return 0;
}
```

this works. But I guess I store two times `InYourFace()`, so I did some searches and found what Tyler McHenry wrote ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353973/c-template-linking-error)),

> BlockquoteTemplates functions, including member functions, must be written entirely in headers.

so I did it. But I would like to understand, because irc all of my teachers tell to don't write functions in a header. So is it really correct to write templates in headers ? or there is another way to write them in cc files, I mean a different way that one I used before, because doesn't sound really efficient if I need to change the template... and what does exactly the compiler when I use a template ? here I used a `string` and `int` so I guess the compiler create `InYourFace(int)` and `InYourFace(string)` and I guess if I call in `main.cc` thirty times `InYourFace(int)` it will not create thirty times `InYourFace(int)` but create only one and uses it thirty times. But if I use `InYourFace(int)` in `ChildrenOfBodom.cc`, does it will create `InYourFace(int)` too, or it will create `InYourFace(int)` one time only for `main.cc` and `ChildrenOfBodom.cc` ?

Hope my question and my english are clear...

Comment: A general hint is to usually put templated definitions only in header files. (i.e. move definition of `template<typename T1>void InYourFace(T1 t1)` -with its body- to file `ChildrenOfBodom.h`

Comment: `template` functions aren't functions.  They are instructions on how to write a function, after the `template` parameters are supplied.  They participate in overload resolution (the compiler says "what kind of function could I generate from this `template`?), and there is deduction magic where their arguments are inferred from what you pass to the `template` function: but until the types are fixed, they aren't functions.  In order to produce the function "on demand", the compiler needs to be able to see the full body of the `template` function where it is used, basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your teacher was correct.  Templates must be in headers.

See this question: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: was a good link for me thx,I like idea to use a tpp file for template