# Non template friend function of 2 templated classes undefined reference error

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

**Problem Statement:**

Using 2 different Templated classes 1 matrix class and other 1 vectorimp class  and using 1 friend function which is multiply function.

**Error Location**

```
 multiply(matA,p);
in main.cpp
```

Issue:
As I am using non templated function with arugements as templated classes so I am getting error

```
undefined reference to `multiply(matrix<int>, vectorimp<int>)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Error:**

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project Matrix_Vector_Multiplication ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -oMatrix_Vector_Multiplication.exe Vector.o Matrix_Vector_Multiplication_main.o Matrix_Vector_Multiplication.o
Matrix_Vector_Multiplication_main.o: In function `main':
D:\C++ Eclipse projects\Matrix_Vector_Multiplication\Debug/../Matrix_Vector_Multiplication_main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `multiply(matrix<int>, vectorimp<int>)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 1741  ms.
```

**matrix class with .h and .cpp file:**

**matrix.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <ostream>
#include "Vector.h"
#define LENGTH 3
#define WIDTH  3

//using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class vectorimp;
template <typename T>
class matrix
  {
private:
    T rows ;
    T cols ;
    T g[LENGTH];
    T **mat;

public:
    //Default constructor
    matrix(T rows , T cols);
    ~matrix();
    T **generatematrix(int rows, int cols);
    void populatematrix(T *src, T size);
    void print();
    template<class T>
    friend void multiply(matrix<T> p, vectorimp<T> v);
  };
```

**matrix.cpp**

```
#include "Matrix_Vector_Multiplication.h"
#include <omp.h>
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
template <class T>
matrix<T>::matrix (T rows , T cols) : rows(rows),cols(cols) {
    this ->mat = generatematrix(this ->rows ,this ->cols );
}
template <class T>
matrix<T>::~matrix()
{
    for(int i=0; i< this->rows; i++)
    {
        delete[] this ->mat[i];
    }
}
template <class T>
T **matrix<T> ::generatematrix (int rows, int cols){
    T **temp = new int*[rows];

    for(int i =0; i< rows; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = new int[cols];
    }
    return temp;
}
template <class T>
void matrix<T> ::print()
{
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j =0; j<cols; j++)
        {
            std::cout<<mat[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
template <class T>
void matrix<T>::populatematrix(T *src, T size)
{
    if (rows * cols !=size){
        cout<<"size of matrix is not equal to size of array"<< endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    int pos =0;
    for(int i=0;i<rows; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<cols; j++){
            this->mat[i][j]=src[pos++];
        }
    }
}
template <class T>
void multiply (matrix<T> p, vectorimp<T> v)
{
  #pragma omp parallel
   int g[3];
   for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        g[i]=0;
   }
   //multiplication.
 //  clock_t start = clock();
      #pragma omp for
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
       {
          // std::cout << "I am here "<< (v.vec[i][j])<<std::endl;
            g[i] = g[i]+( p.mat[i][j] * v.vec[j]);

       }
        std::cout << "I am here "<< g[i]<<std::endl;
  /*  clock_t stop = clock();
        printf("Computing time = %0.9fus\n",
               double(stop - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);*/
  }
}

template class matrix<int>;
```

**vector.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <ostream>
#include "Matrix_Vector_Multiplication.h"

template <typename T>
class matrix;
template <typename T>
class vectorimp
  {
private:
    int vec[3];
    T vec3D[3][3];
    T size;
    T recent;

public:
    //Default constructor
    vectorimp();
    // Destructor
    ~vectorimp();
    // function to get assign desired values to the vector
    void populate_vector1D(std::vector <std::vector<T> > &data);
    template<class T>
    friend void multiply(matrix<T> p, vectorimp<T> v);
  };
```

**vector.cpp**

```
#include "Vector.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
vectorimp<T>::vectorimp(){
    //vec = vec[4][4];
     size = 1;
     recent =0;
}
template <class T>
vectorimp<T>::~vectorimp(){}

template <class T>
void vectorimp<T>::populate_vector1D(std::vector <std::vector<T> > &data)
{
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
   { // printing the 2D vector.
      for (unsigned int j = 0; j < data[i].size(); j++)
      {
        vec[i]   = data[i][j];
      }
   }
}
template class vectorimp <int>;
```

**main.cpp file**

```
#include "Matrix_Vector_Multiplication.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

      int srcA[]= {2,4,3,1,5,7,0,2,3};
      matrix<int> matA(3,3);
      matA.populatematrix (srcA,9);
      std::vector<std::vector<int> > v{ { 2,4,3 },
        { 5,1,6 },
        { 6,3,2 } };
        vectorimp<int> p;
        p.populate_vector1D(v);
        multiply(matA,p);
        return 0;
}
```

To be honest I am not an expert in coding so getting confused in using templates. Thanks a lot for help in advance.

**Disclaimer:**

```
Checked out the avaiable resources  like 
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353973/c-template-linking-error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?rq=1
and few more
```

Comment: @drescherjm please see the disclaimer I have checked these links. Thanks a lot for sharing again.

Comment: You forgot to explicitly specialize `multiply`.

Comment: `template <class T>
void multiply (matrix<T> p, vectorimp<T> v) != void multiply(matrix<T> p, vectorimp<T> v)`

Comment: @Dani Thanks for your comment Can you please elaborate a bit I did not catch it

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks a lot but if I remove    `template <class T> `    from   `template <class T>  void multiply (matrix<T> p, vectorimp<T> v)` it will not work as the arguments are templates

Comment: @NathanOliver do yu suggest some solution or remedy to this issue as i remained unable to find it somehow

Comment: Make the friend function declaration a template as well so that it matches the definition.

Comment: @NathanOliver like this    ` template<class T> `   and function 
              ` friend void multiply(matrix<T> p, vectorimp<T> v) ` but it still gives the same error in `multiply(matA,p)` please check the edit also i have done the declaration as templated

Comment: see dani's comment.  This is why you should put all template code in the header file.

Comment: @NathanOliver you are right but right now my demand is not to do it in 1 file as this is an example my code is quite big so I have to make .h and .cpp file separately and for Dani comment to be honest I also did not get it what does it means by explicitly specialize `multiply`

Comment: @john: Add at the end of matrix.cpp `template void multiply (matrix<int> p, vectorimp<int> v)`

Comment: @Dani thanks for getting back to me unfortunately it is after implementing your suggestion it is stil giving errors. Incase if it is fine for you can you provide me some working solution. The problem is I cannot also provide the link of code in online compiler as it works there

Comment: @Dani: That’s what is needed, but it’s an explicit *instantiation*, not a specialization.

Answer (score 0):

There are two suggestions I would like to make, first of all, put your header and cpp files together as you are using template, Secondly please look at the following line of code:

```
vectorimp<T>::~vectorimp(){}
```

You did nothing in the destructor this is dangerous, try adding in something like delete[] vec, Also from the line above:

```
vec = vec[4][4];
```

It looks like you are trying to intialize a 2D vector, but in your declaration:

```
int vec[3]
```

Dangerous.....

```
T vec3D[3][3];
```

Declaring this guy but you never intialized it with your constructor.
then you called this guy:

```
vectorimp<int> p;
```

Which intializes your vec3D to nullptr.
Finally you decided to pass this nullptr object to your method populate1D:
and do the following call:

```
vec[i] = data[i][j]
```

Which since vec is nullptr, program breaks.

Comment: There are no `nullptr` problems here. `vec[i] = data[i][j]` will cause problems if there are more `data` elements than reserved space in `vec`, but `populate1D` verifies the size of `data` (`data.size()` and `data[i].size()`) so no nullptr problem in that case. There are many other problems, though, as this is a very naive design.

Comment: but it is declared as `int vec[3]`, which is not a `nullptr`, just an array of 3 `int`.

Comment: Oops I didn't see that, although this way of solving the problem is new to me, I never seen anyone intialize the elements of a static array with a vector before???

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `multiply(matrix<int>, vectorimp<int>)` in a `cpp` file, which is an independent compilation unit and thus, not seen outside that file. The templates are instantiated when used/needed, but if it is used in a different compilation unit, the compiler hasn't the function body so it is undefined.
You have to put the function body in the header, so the function body is available for all compilation units (`cpp` files) that need it.

```
template <class T>
void multiply (matrix<T> p, vectorimp<T> v);

template <typename T>
class matrix
  {
public:
    friend void multiply<>(matrix<T> p, vectorimp<T> v);
  };

template <class T>
void multiply (matrix<T> p, vectorimp<T> v)
{
    // whatever
}
```

You have to declare the `friend` function before the `class matrix` and/or `class vectorimp`, then tell the compiler it is a template function. You can't put the `template<class T>` in the friend declaration inside the `class` because it shadows the template parameter, so simply `multiply<>` (with angles.)

You have other errors, as not creating a coy constructor. `multiply` function will receive a *copy* of the `matrix` and `vectorimp` parameters; when the function returns the copies will be `delete`d and when the program ends you will have a double deletion.

If you pass parameters by reference there will by no double deletion.

In `matrix::~matrix` you have to delete `mat` to avoid memory leak.

```
    for (int i=0; i < this->cols; i++)
    {
        delete [] this->mat[i];
    }
    delete [] this->mat;
```

You are allocating `int`s for an unknown type `T`:

```
T **temp = new int*[rows];
```

This should be:

```
T **temp = new T*[rows];
```

And you are mixing indexes with the template type:

```
T rows ;
T cols ;
```

Those are independent of the parameter type.

If you make those changes it will work without memory leaks:

```
manuel@desktop:~/projects$ g++ -Wall main.cc -o main -std=c++17 && valgrind --leak-check=full ./main
==16701== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16701== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16701== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16701== Command: ./main
==16701== 
I am here 36
I am here 47
I am here 18
==16701== 
==16701== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16701==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16701==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 13 frees, 73,932 bytes allocated
==16701== 
==16701== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16701== 
==16701== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16701== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

There are also lots of hard coded array indexes (value `3`) in declarations and loops that will break if there are `matrix` and/or `vector` size changes in `main`.